# After calling an API, parsing results of getJSON()

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson

My compiler seems to not go into the getJSON() function as nothing is coming on the console.Also,the result is of nested json format and I am not sure whether I am writing correct code to access the nested data.Also,do I need to specify the type of method i.e. GET with this method?This is the link to my Codepen [Link](https://codepen.io/asinha/full/LWpyOE)

```
  var url=api+"lat="+lat+"&lon="+lon+"&APPID=3346fe595f3b91ee6307913c28042901"+cb;
       //console.log(url);
       $.getJSON(url,function(jsonResult){
         //alert("hey");
         //console.log("hello");
         var temp=jsonResult.main.temp;
         $("#results").html(temp);
       }).fail(function() {
    console.log( "Request Failed: " );
});
```

Comment: Do you see the request being made in the Network tab of the dev tools? Also, the lat, lon,APPID etc should be passed as an object to the data param of getJSON(). First thing to check though is if you see the request being made in Network tab.

Comment: how do I check that? @creativekinetix

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: chrome @creativekinetix I have given the link to my codepen if you could have a look into it

Comment: You can see network activity in Developer console. Go to View > Developer > Developer Console > Network Tab

Comment: Also, try adding a second callback to your getCurrentPosition(success, failure) and console.log that as well. Do you see the console.log(lat,lon) in the console? I'll take a look at the code a little more later today and post what I find.